# Is it possible to model a min-max-problem using pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

Ist it possible to formulate a min-max-optimization problem of the following form in pyomo:

`min(max(g_m(x)) s.t. L`

where g_m are nonlinear functions (actually constrains of another model) and L is a set of linear constrains?

How would I create the expression for the objective function of the model?

The problem is that using `max()` on a list of constraint-objects returns only the constraint possessesing the maximum value at a given point.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, but unless you find a clever way to reformulate your model, it might not be very efficent.

You could solve all possiblity of `max(g_m(x))`, then select the solution with the lowest objective function value.

I fear that the `max` operation is not something you can add to a minimization model, since it is not a mathematical operation, but a solver operation. This operation is on the problems level. Keep in mind that when solving a model, Pyomo requires as argument only one `sense` of optimization (min or max), thus making it unable to understand min-max sense. Even if it did, how could it knows what to maximize or minimize? This is why I suggest you to break your problem in two, unless you work on its formulation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I realized the same. Using the epigraph, I use the following model instead, which serves my purpose:

```min a s.t. L and g_m(x)<=a```.

In class I always wondered why this reformulation is important. Now I know why.

Comment: I am very glad you found a way to do this, congrats! Keep in mind that you can always answer your own question and mark it as answer. This will help other users to solve the problem the way you did! Anyway, take care!